# Can you install unstable packages just with command-line?

Tags: php, composer-php

To install the latest development version of a given package and get over the *conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability* error I understand I have to create a `composer.json` file and set `minimum-stability` to `dev`.

**Is it possible to grant the appropriate permissions right from the command-line with a reasonably simple command or command set?**

---

Apparently, the only command that has a `--stability` argument is [composer init](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#init) but it forces you to get through and endless interrogation that only gets on the way when you're about to write code not for Packagist:

```
C:\tmp\foo>composer init --stability dev


  Welcome to the Composer config generator



This command will guide you through creating your composer.json config.

Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [alvaro.gonzalez/foo]:
Description []:
Author [, n to skip]: n
Minimum Stability [dev]:
Package Type (e.g. library, project, metapackage, composer-plugin) []:
License []:

Define your dependencies.

Would you like to define your dependencies (require) interactively [yes]? no
Would you like to define your dev dependencies (require-dev) interactively [yes]? no

{
    "name": "alvaro.gonzalez/foo",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {}
}

Do you confirm generation [yes]?

C:\tmp\foo>
```

Comment: Why don't you just write to the composer file by hand?

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. It's just I'm interested in a pure command-line solution and I want to ensure I'm not missing a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `composer config minimum-stability dev`

The full oneliner would be
`composer init --name=alvaro.gonzalez/foo --no-interaction; composer config minimum-stability dev`

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm it also works with empty JSON, as in `echo {} > composer.json & composer config minimum-stability dev` (note: this command is for Windows command prompt; Linux shells will probably need proper escaping as well as `&&`).

Comment: Is it possible to append a `prefer-stable` setting on here also? I notice when I install a package with a `minimum-stability` of `dev` everything that gets installed along with that package also seems to drop to dev versions.

Comment: @inspirednz sure, you can add `composer config prefer-stable true` to the command